# Call a globla snackbar vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i have this global snackbar in my SnackBarGeneral.vue file

```
<template>
  <v-snackbar class="mt-5" v-model="localValue" :color="colorRecibido" top>
    {{ mensajeSnackBarRecibido }}

    <template v-slot:action="{ attrs }">
      <v-icon right v-bind="attrs" @click="localValue = false">
        mdi-close
      </v-icon>
    </template>
  </v-snackbar>
</template>

export default {
  name: "SnackBarGeneral",

  props: {
    colorRecibido: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: "success",
    },
    mensajeSnackBarRecibido: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: "Mensaje Vacio",
    },
    value: {
      required: true,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      mensajeSnackBar: null,
      colorsnackbar: null,
      localValue: null,
    };
  },

  watch: {
    localValue(newValue) {
      this.$emit("input", newValue);
    },
    value(newValue) {
      this.localValue = newValue;
    },
  },
};
```

here in call the snackbar send it the value to show it, the message i want to show, and the color i want it has:

```
<SnackBarGeneral
      :colorRecibido="colorSnackBar"
      :mensajeSnackBarRecibido="mensajeSnackBar"
      :value="value"
    >
    </SnackBarGeneral>
<script>
import SnackBarGeneral from "@/components/SnackBarGeneral.vue";

export default {
  components: { modalBuscarCliente, SnackBarGeneral },
  data: () => ({
    value: false,
    colorSnackBar: "red",
    mensajeSnackBar: "",
  },
  methods: {
       callSnackBar() {
        this.mensajeSnackBar = "Revise todos los campos del formulario";
        this.colorSnackBar = "red";
        this.value = true;
    },
  },
};
```

but when i call the function to show the snackbar, it only shows me the snackbar with the correct message once time, but if i call it again it doesnt work:

Comment: `callSnackBar()` only ever sets the message to a static string. Why would you expect it to show a different message when that function is called again?

Comment: because i call the function in others part of the proyect and it sets another text in the string, but the problem it's only work once time, if i want to call it a second or three time it doesnt work

Comment: Show how the other calls are setting the text in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a key to your `SnackBarGeneral`. It might be because it's not rendering again.

```
<SnackBarGeneral
  :colorRecibido="colorSnackBar"
  :mensajeSnackBarRecibido="mensajeSnackBar"
  :value="value"
  :key="snackKey"
>
</SnackBarGeneral>
```

Initialize the `snackKey` and increment it in your `callSnackBar()` method.

I hope this helps you.